# How to use JOIN instead of sub query (NOT IN)

Tags: mysql, sql, select, join, query-performance

I want to list all people that `$_SESSION['userid']` follows and not follows

This query below is for follows cast, it works

**IN** (slow)

```
SELECT user.* FROM user 
WHERE user.userid 
     IN (SELECT follow.followtoid FROM follow 
WHERE follow.followerid = $_SESSION['userid'])
```

**JOIN** (fast)

```
SELECT p.* 
FROM user p
    JOIN follow f ON p.userid = f.followtoid
WHERE f.followerid = $_SESSION['userid']
```

For those still not follow cast, it works but seems very slow
Please suggest me how do i use JOIN instead of NOT IN

**NOT IN** (slow)

```
SELECT user.* FROM user 
WHERE user.userid 
     NOT IN (SELECT follow.followtoid FROM follow 
WHERE follow.followerid = $_SESSION['userid'])
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `LEFT JOIN` and eliminate all rows that have matches;

```
SELECT p.* 
FROM user p
LEFT JOIN follow f 
  ON p.userid = f.followtoid
 AND f.followerid = $_SESSION['userid']
WHERE f.followtoid IS NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT u.* 
FROM user u
LEFT JOIN follow f ON u.userid = f.followtoid AND f.followerid = $_SESSION['userid']
WHERE f.followtoid IS NULL;
```

**OR**

```
SELECT u.* 
FROM user u
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM follow f 
                  WHERE u.userid = f.followtoid AND f.followerid = $_SESSION['userid']
                 );
```